# Setting Up iPhone Virtual Machines to Test HTML Emails on Multiple Devices?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, qemu

I am attempting to create virtual machines for various iPhone models with different iOS versions to test the appearance of HTML emails on multiple devices.

For instance, I'd like to launch a simulator for the iPhone 11, where I can install Apple Mail, Gmail, and Outlook apps to assess their display. I'm interested in replicating this process for other iPhone and iPad versions as well.

However, I've encountered issues as Xcode doesn't permit the installation of App Store apps. I've also experimented with emulators like UTM and QEMU but have not successfully executed them.

Consequently, I have several inquiries:

Is there a method to install App Store apps, such as Gmail, within Xcode? I've considered jailbreaking but haven't found any viable solutions. Another option could be obtaining app builds, which seems improbable. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Is it feasible to use UTM, QEMU, or another emulator for this purpose? I have downloaded a few iPhone firmware from https://ipsw.me/, but I have yet to make them work.

Can you think of any alternative approaches to accomplish this task?

For context, I am trying to develop a local solution similar to Litmus or Email on Acid, which test HTML emails on a wide range of devices. I'd like to create something comparable for multiple phones to expedite testing.